# How to convert Execl sheet filled with data like Form to data like Tabular?

Tags: excel

How to convert Execl sheet filled with data like Form to data like Tabular please find the next screenshot :

[image: the sheet]

All i need transpose the data with limiting the header columns to one row then the data comes after.

Note : the headers is A column and B is the Data.

Example for the result required :

[image: Result Required]

I tried to copy all the A and B Columns and Special Paste them it giving me error as the next screenshots :

[image: The Copy]

[image: The Error]
Please offer me a help or workaround thanks in advance .

Comment: What is your programming or formula problem?  What have you tried? What has gone wrong with that?  Please note that this is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop.

Comment: Copy, paste special transpose. Nothing more to it unless your question is missing more information?

Comment: Hi guys,
First i don't need help in code i just need help from your knowledge
Second @QHarr I absolutely tried this method but it giving me error
"we can't paste because the copy area aren't the same size"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the original data is in sheet *source*.  In another sheet, copy the 5 desriptors and PasteSpecialTranspose into the first row of the new sheet.

Then in cell **A2** of the new sheet enter:

```
=INDEX(source!$B:$B,COLUMNS($A:A)+5*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)
```

copy this formula both across and downward.

Source data:

[image]

New Sheet:

[image]

Note the constant **5** in the formula corresponds to the number of descriptors in the source data.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved it like magic  i add something to make it easier to copy the formula 

=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,COLUMNS($A:A)+5*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)

Comment: @alaadinibrahim  Good Job!

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student 
Can you suggest better title for this question so it can help more people ?

Comment: please check the new title and give me your opinion.